# Is restrict "right" for posix_spawn?

Tags: c, linux

So I see that the header file spawn.h makes heavy use of 'restrict':

```
extern int posix_spawn (pid_t *__restrict __pid,
        const char *__restrict __path,
        const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *__restrict
        __file_actions,
        const posix_spawnattr_t *__restrict __attrp,
        char *const __argv[__restrict_arr],
        char *const __envp[__restrict_arr]);
```

- Interestingly, posix_spawnp does not.

But a use pattern I regularly have for the exec family of calls is:

```
const char* command = "whatever";
const char* args[] = {command, "--arg1", "--arg2"};
```

Now, the exec family, /don't/ use restrict, so I can (ignoring a few const casts)

```
execv(command, args);
```

But I (technically) can't do the following because of restrict: __path and 
 __argv are both tagged restricted, so can't point to the same object.

```
posix_spawn(nullptr, command, nullptr, nullptr, args, __environ);
```

Is this sensible at some profound level that I am unaware of? :-)
Of course it is all wrapped in macros so perhaps this has never been enabled?

Note this question is very much in the land of hypotheticals and language lawyers. I haven't found a compile or lint option which enforces this restriction, and certainly not from C++, with extern "C", but equally I don't want to walk into one in the future.

Comment: So which part of your call to `posix_spawn` is falling foul of `restrict`? I see other problems, such as your `args` array not being `NULL` terminated, and  some incompatibilities between `const char **` and `char * const *` (presumably the "ignoring a few const casts" you mentioned in your question). Also, `nullptr` should be `NULL` since you tagged the question as [tag:c].

Comment: None, because I don't have the compiler and lint setting to enforce restrict, and mainly calling from C++ where restrict maybe gets ignored anyway, but the question is just in principle, not in practice.

Comment: Okay, I really meant which part of your call to `posix_spawn` do you *think* falls foul of `restrict` and why?

Comment: Added to that effect. argv and path.

Comment: You used the same `char` pointer for `__path` and `__argv[0]`, but I don't think that falls foul of `restrict` because of the indirection in `__argv[0]`.

Comment: It is pretty useless if restrict only restricts the top level. Perhaps that is why it hasn't been adopted to c++. Given that all the arguments are very distinct types, what is the point of restrict here at all, then?

Comment: I think the point of restrict is to remind us that participation in standards bodies should be modelled on jury selection -- volunteers are not permitted.   Restrict is a half thought out idea that is applied even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is useful to the compiler of the `posix_spawn` function itself.

It tells the compiler what he may assume about the arrays. In particular it tells that the first arguments can't be aliased by the character array: 
`char*` and similar can alias all other pointer types.

This may be obvious to you and any other human (who would pass a `char*`-converted `pid_t*` as a path?) but it is not to the compiler.

Similar arguments hold for the other arrays. If their base types are just some `typedef`ed integer type, the compiler could suspect aliasing where in fact there will never be.

For the code that you showed there is no problem, because `restrict` protects the object it points to, not other objects that are referenced by that. If someone wanted that, he'd have to use something like

```
char *restrict const __argv[restrict],
```

but this would probably be too "restrictive", here.

Comment: [sorry been ill] I guess in the end you are right. With C not having inheritance, any struct could be related to any other struct, so the compiler really does have no way of knowing that two pointer types are unrelated and therefore non-sharable. I was under the mistaken belief that putting restrict inside the array bracket had the effect of restricting the array content, but it seems this was just some language writer's cheat.